# C++ Winapi - How to draw a fill shape rectangle and set the border thickness?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to draw a rectangle with a border.

```
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            
FillRect((HDC)wParam, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0)));      //black fill
FrameRect((HDC)wParam, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0)));   //red border
```

The above code works, though I'm not actually sure if that's the proper way to do it.

Anyway, I would like to set the thickness of the border. But I'm having a hard time figuring how. Can anyone can point me in the right direction or much better give a working example?

Comment: For classic GDI create brush - HBRUSH (for fill) and pen - HPEN (for border), select them into DC and use `Rectangle` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [GDI+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-gdi-start) is allowed then this is how I'll do it

```
int width = 100;        //set the width.
int height = 100;       //set the height.
int borderSize = 5;     //set border size.
        
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd); //don't forget to release later when done. 
Graphics g(hdc);        
        
SolidBrush brush((Color(255, 241, 103, 210)));  //Set the fill color.
Pen pen(Color(255,255, 0, 0), borderSize);      //Set the border color and border size.

width = width-borderSize;                       //deduct the border size to width to get the same point we wanted, for border only.
height = height-borderSize;                     //deduct the border size to height to get the same point we wanted, for border only

g.DrawRectangle(&pen, (borderSize / 2), (borderSize / 2), width, height); //draw the border
g.FillRectangle(&brush, borderSize, borderSize, width-borderSize, height - borderSize); //draw the fill shape, and again deduct the border size to the width and height to get the same point we wanted.
        
DeleteObject(&brush);   //always delete object 
DeleteObject(&pen);     //always delete object
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);   //always release hdc
```

It's a little tricky, refer to the comments for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`FrameRect` documentation says

> The width and height of the border are always one logical unit.

So, one option is to change the mapping between logical units and physical units.  If you don't want to mess up subsequent drawing operations, you'll have to save the old mapping and restore it after drawing your rectangle and frame.  And the rectangle dimensions will need to change when the mapping changes.  What a mess!

A better and simpler option is to stop using `FrameRect`.  Simply use `FillRect` and the border brush, then `DeflateRect` to obtain a rectangle representing the interior, and `FillRect` that rectangle with your fill brush.  The parameters to `DeflateRect` will determine the border thickness.

This doesn't work for creating hollow borders the way that `FrameRect` does, but for a border on a filled rectangle it is an elegant solution.